# Converting grouped stacked columns into multiple columns by grouping in Pandas

Tags: pandas, grouping

I've organized my dataframe to look something like this using the groupby function:

```
Compound   Sample    Concentration  x   y
Benzene    A         15             Ax  Ay 
           B         20             Bx  By
           C         17             Cx  Cy

Toluene    A         23             Ax  Ay
           B         40             Bx  By

Xylene     A         70             Ax  Ay
           B         62             Bx  By
           C         55             Cx  Cy
           D         32             Dx  Dy
```

How do I unstack the column into multiple columns of the same height with the groupings as the column names? I want to achieve something like this:

```
Sample    Benzene   Toluene    Xylene    x   y
A         15        23         70        Ax  Ay 
B         20        40         62        Bx  By
C         17        0          55        Cx  Cy
D         0         0          32        Dx  Dy
```

Edit
I lost the indexes after I used the groupby function, my data used to look like this:

```
    Compound       Sample        Concentration          x   y
1    Benzene       A             15                     Ax  Ay 
5    Benzene       B             20                     Bx  By
6    Benzene       C             17                     Cx  Cy
0    Toluene       A             23                     Ax  Ay
4    Toluene       B             40                     Bx  By
2    Xylene        A             70                     Ax  Ay
3    Xylene        B             62                     Bx  By
7    Xylene        C             55                     Cx  Cy
8    Xylene        D             32                     Dx  Dy
```

I sorted by Compound so that rearranged all the indexes, which are initially sorted by sample

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your posting, it's not really clear which of your columns are in the index. If none of them are (which you can force with df.reset_index()), then you can do the following:

```
df.set_index(['Compound', 'Sample', 'x', 'y'], inplace = True)
df = df['Concentration']
df = df.unstack(level = 0)
df.reset_index(inplace = True)
```

the only way that this doesn't match your output is that the x and y columns are on the left of your data now. Since it looks like those columns are built easily from the sample letter, it might be easier to add them in after this transformation. That is, if your group by gave you a dataframe with compound and sample in the index, and concentration as the only column, you could just do:

```
df = df['Concentration'].unstack(level = 0)
```

and then add your x and y columns.

Edit: From your original data, you could also do this, which does what you did with the groupby and reshapes in in one step:

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['Sample', 'x', 'y'], columns = 'Compound', values = 'Concentration')
```

Comment: The groupby function makes the columns you are grouping by the index unless you specifically tell it not to with the as_index = False option). The fact that the compound name isn't displayed in every row makes me think it is part of the index.

Comment: I grouped by all of the columns, so I may have put all of the values in the index? I am not exactly sure how it works. I've edited my question to show how the it looked before I used the groupby function.